# mxCodec doesn't decode xml correctly

Tags: reactjs, mxgraph

I integrated mxGraph(`mxgraph` npm package) in my react app, so when I trying to load graph using xml, I am getting an error in console

```
TypeError: geo.clone is not a function
```

The same I am doing in single html file and it's working.

I investigated and found that the `mxCell` in react app is different from the html one.

In case of HTML there is filled `geometry` prop instead of react(check screens below)

Сan someone help me to decode xml correctly?

*Decoded `mxCell` from single HTML console:* https://monosnap.com/file/yAHAi29zFGFpauqU2RtDcvmfPpZ0YJ

*Decoded `mxCell` from React app console:* https://monosnap.com/file/0XxPwyEracX7hMCnMHckAmI8Rl6OEh

Source code from React component:

```
const graph = new mx.mxGraph(this.automationRef.current)
new mx.mxRubberband(graph);

const xml = '<root>...</root>';
const doc = mx.mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
const codec = new mxCodec(doc);
let elt = doc.documentElement.firstChild;
const cells = [];
while (elt != null){
  const cell = codec.decodeCell(elt)
  cells.push(cell);
  graph.refresh();
  elt = elt.nextSibling;
}

graph.addCells(cells);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.
Here's the solution:

https://github.com/jgraph/mxgraph/issues/301#issuecomment-514284868

**Quote:**

*you should add*

```
window['mxGraphModel'] = mxGraphModel;
window['mxGeometry'] = mxGeometry;
```

*before*

```
let doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
let codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());'
```

*I found that the decode method resolve xml need windows param*

**End quote**